# Почему не работает мною написанный код в Code Blocks на С++

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, ".1251");
    double x, a, b, e, l;
    a = 0,5;
    b = 1;
    e = 0,0001;

    while(abs(b - a) > e)
    {
        x = (a + b) / 2;
        l = ((a * a - 10 * log10(a) - 3) * (x * x - 10 * log10(x) - 3));

        if (l < 0)
            b = x;
        else
            a = x;

        if (abs(b - a) < e)
            cout << x ;
    }
}
```

Comment: вообщем то я пока, что новичок и пока что начал только изучать C++ и мне надо вывести корни заданной функции методом деление отрезка пополам, но почему то не выводиться число x по заданным условиям

Comment: Когда вы пишите «не работает», уточняйте что именно и как.

Comment: @alexolut просто там корень x не выводиться, вообщем запускаю и только курсок как бы мигает и ничего не выдаёт

Comment: @HasmikGaryaka большое спасибо вам! всё заработало!)

Answer (score 6):

В строке, где задается е, нужно не запятую писать, а точку. Десятичные дроби в английском через точку пишутся. У вас получилось е=0,1. Запятая интерпретируется как оператор, значение выражения равно второму подвыражению.
[Что такое запятая](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/zs06xbxh.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

Выполняется оператор e=0, и затем 1, но 1 ничему не присваивается.
Точно так же a у вас равно не 0.5, как вы хотели, а 0. Соответственно программа работает не на том интервале с эпсилон =0, и условие не выполняется.

Comment: Причем здесь английский? Язык C++ там требует точку, а не английский!

Comment: Авторы языка были англоговорящими, поэтому и требует.

Comment: автор C++ датчанин вообще-то

Comment: Страуструп? А он при чем, если он делал на основе С. Писал книги он на английском.

Comment: Про приоритет запятой и присваивания еще не забудьте посмотреть, прежде чем о значениях говорить.

Comment: @alexolut А что не так с приоритетами? Приоритет запятой самый низкий, так что, как написал  @HasmikGaryaka, значением выражения `e=0,0001;` таки будет 1, а значением `e` - нуль... Нет?

Comment: Да, я ответ отредактировала.

Comment: @Harry см. список редакций.

Comment: @alexolut Понял, спасибо.